# Unable to satisfy Into<i64> trait bound

Tags: rust, traits

For some reason I couldn't figure anything out from searching the web.

So I have a type synonym using the `libc` crate (a simple wrapper):

```rs
pub type SyscallResult<R: Into<i64>> = Result<R, c_int>;
```

The point of having the `Into<i64>` is because some syscalls have `i32` or `i64` results but `errno` is always an `i32`. (`c_int` -> `i32`)

There was no problems using concrete types provided by `std` in the function signature.

```rs
pub fn handle_syscall_result(result: SyscallResult<i64>) -> i64
{
    match result {
        Ok(status: i64) => status,
        Err(errno: c_int) => {
            let err = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(libc::strerror(errno)) };
            println!("{:?}", err);
            errno as i64
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to propagate the trait bound into the signature of a function, things start to go haywire:

```rs
fn new_syscall_result<T>(status: Option<T>) -> SyscallResult<i64>
where
    T: Into::<i64>,
{
    let errno: c_int = errno();

    match errno {
        -1 => Err(errno),
        _ => Ok(status.unwrap_or(errno)),
    }
}
```

Gives

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> 
   |
35 | fn new_syscall_result<T>(status: Option<T>) -> SyscallResult<i64>
   |                       - this type parameter
...
43 |         _ => Ok(status.unwrap_or(errno)),
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `i64`, found type parameter `T`
   |
   = note:        expected type `i64`
           found type parameter `T`
```

which makes it look like it is doing the right thing, as the `i32` was casted to an `i64`, yet for some reason it doesn't satisfy the trait bound `T`?

Unwrapping `Option<T>` should naturally give `T` and from what I've read from the `std::convert::From` docs, `Into<i64>` should be implemented for `i64` as well (reflexivity), though even if it wasn't casted `From<i32> for i64` is a valid implementation which means `Into<i64> for i32` should exist.

Switching the return type to `SyscallResult<T>` doesn't make a difference either

```rs
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> 
   |
35 | fn new_syscall_result<T>(status: Option<T>) -> SyscallResult<T>
   |                       - this type parameter
...
43 |         _ => Ok(status.unwrap_or(errno)),
   |                                  ^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `i32`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `i32`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly call `into()`:

```rust
        _ => Ok(status.map(Into::<i64>::into).unwrap_or(errno.into())),
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`status` is a `Option<T>`, bot you want an `Option<i64>`. To achieve this, we transform the type contained in the `Option` by using `Option::map`.

There is another problem in your code:

```rust
        _ => Ok(status.map(Into::<i64>::into).unwrap_or(errno.into())),
//                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`errno` is a `c_int`, so on most platforms a `i32`, but we need an `i64`. Again, `into()` must be used to transform the type. Explicit type annotations are not necessary here, the compiler can deduce the correct type from context. Alternatively, you could also use a cast here:

```rust
        _ => Ok(status.map(Into::<i64>::into).unwrap_or(errno as i64)),
```